# Elasticsearch exact match or query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents like this in my index:

```
{
  "field" : "a, b, c, d, e"
}
```

The field value is a string made by a array to string function. So not every document has the same string but every document has at least `"a, b"` as value.

Now I would like to have a query which is matching 2 kinds of documents:

Documents which have only(exactly) `"a, b"` as field value or documents which contain at least two searchterms in the field.

Basically my problem is that I can't fullfill the first condition if the field gets analyzed and I can"t fulfill the second condition if the fields is not getting analyzed. Is there a solution without cloning the field as  not_alanyzed?

If I clone the field to a not analyzed field(in the code example field1) I can use this query. I feel like this query is too complicated for the achievement...:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "or": [
          {
            "term": {
              "field1": "a, b"
            }
          },
          {
            "and": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "field": "c"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "field1": "d"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you currently fulfill the condition "documents which contain at least two search terms in the field"? Could you please post code that searches for documents with only that condition? I might be able to help...

Comment: The and filter in the code example is fulfilling the second condition that u mentioned...

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a multi-field mapping. This allows a field to be sent once, but analyzed in two different ways.

```
"properties": {
  "field" {
    "type": "multi_field",
      "fields" : {
        "field" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed"},
        "raw" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
    }
  }
}
```

Send the document to elasticsearch as normal (it will get indexed in two places, `field` (or `field.field`) and `field.raw`

Now your query will look like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "or": [
          {
            "term": {
              "field.raw": "a, b"
            }
          },
          {
            "and": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "field": "c"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "field": "d"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's not the most elegant solution. I would much prefer changing the way you store the data. It seems like "a, b" represents something different, maybe have a boolean field "a_b_only" on the doc to filter by.

Good luck, and please feel free to ask for more help!

Comment: Thanks for the advice I created an additional boolean field while indexing and can use an easy query now to get all docs which contain only "a, b"

Answer (score 3):

multi_fields are not supported in Elasticsearch version 1.X instead use

```
"title" :{ 
           "type" : "string",
            "raw" : {"type" :"string" , "index" :"not_analyzed" 
         }
```

For more information please read [Elasticsearch 1.7 Docs on Multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/_multi_fields.html).

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, why did you make a string from your array in the first place? A field in an ES document can hold multiple values, and you can query them using the 'terms' filter: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/terms-filter/. So instead of your original field data:

```
{
  "field1" : "a, b, c, d, e"
}
```

you'd just keep it in an array, like so:

```
{
  "field1" : ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
}
```

and then you'd query something like this (beware, this is untested!):

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "or": [
          {
            "terms": {
              "field1": ["a", "b"],
              "execution": "and"
            }
          },
          {
            "terms": {
              "field1": ["c", "d"],
              "execution": "and"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As a final note, I'd think that your real data requires that 'field1' is set to be 'not_analyzed'.

Comment: This wouldn't work for me because all field1 values contain "a", "b" but only some contain exactly(only) "a", "b". Your query would match every of my docs.... That is also why I converted the array into a string. Because I need that exact match.

Comment: Ah yes, I do see what you mean now. I misunderstood the problem - I'm glad you found a solution!